# Gradle - How to force dependencies into the WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, gradle, war

I'm looking to copy dependency jars into the war file's `WEB-INF/lib` directory whether they're transitive of the project or not. Is there a way to accomplish this?

My `build.gradle` is below and I've tried multiple options. Is there a way to ensure that a specific set of jars appears in the war no matter what?

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
}

war {
    manifest { attributes("Class-Path": "resources/") }
    version = null
}

//Does not contain the jackson libraries
providedCompile project(":components:Manager")

dependencies {
    //Doesn't work
    implementation libraries.jackson_core
    implementation libraries.jackson_databind
    implementation libraries.jackson_annotations
    
    providedCompile(
            //Doesn't work
            libraries.jackson_core,
            libraries.jackson_databind,
            libraries.jackson_annotations,
            ///
            libraries.mybatis,
            libraries.mybatis_cdi,
            libraries.javax_ejb,
            libraries.javax_rs
    )

    compile "javax:javaee-api:$jeeVersion" //The only jar that appears in the WEB-INF/lib folder
    
    //Doesn't work
    compile(
            libraries.jackson_core,
            libraries.jackson_databind,
            libraries.jackson_annotations,
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by setting up a custom `warLib` `configuration`

[Credit](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2014/09/gradle-goodness-adding-dependencies.html?m=1)

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
}

configurations {
    warLib
}

providedCompile project(":components:Manager")

dependencies {
   
    providedCompile(
            libraries.mybatis,
            libraries.mybatis_cdi,
            libraries.javax_ejb,
            libraries.javax_rs
    )

    compile "javax:javaee-api:$jeeVersion"
    
    warLib libraries.jackson_databind

}

war {
    classpath configurations.warLib
    manifest { attributes("Class-Path": "resources/") }
    version = null
}
```